# Set Tuple of List to ViewData Mvc C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am adding some data in List of Tuple type like this in Razor view

```
   List<Tuple<int, int, string>> Downloadlist = new List<Tuple<int, int, string>>();
```

And adding items to this list

```
         Downloadlist.Add(new Tuple<int, int, string>(11, 7, "somedata"));
```

Now I would like to access the array of data in javascript

```
<script>

    var listofdownloadpages = '@ViewData["DownloadPages"]';
    if (listofdownloadpages != null) {

        alert(listofdownloadpages.length);

        for (var i = 0; i < listofdownloadpages.length; i++) {
            alert(listofdownloadpages[i].wishid + ' ' + listofdownloadpages[i].remain);
        }
    }
    else {
        alert("not found anything");

    }
```

But this not giving me the items in correct way please help.

Comment: Where are you expecting `wishid` and `remain` to magically appear from?  Just use a `class` (and preferably a proper viewmodel) - this isn't really what `Tuple`'s are for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

Controller

```
 public ActionResult Test()
        {
            List<Tuple<int, int, string>> Downloadlist = new List<Tuple<int, int, string>>();
            Downloadlist.Add(new Tuple<int, int, string>(11, 7, "somedata"));

            ViewData["DownloadPages"] = Downloadlist;
            return View();
        }
```

View & JS

```
   <script>
        var listofdownloadpages =  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.DownloadPages));
        if (listofdownloadpages != null) {

            alert(listofdownloadpages.length);

            for (var i = 0; i < listofdownloadpages.length; i++) {
                alert(listofdownloadpages[i].Item1 + ' ' + listofdownloadpages[i].Item2);
            }
        }
        else {
            alert("not found anything");

        }
</script>
```